# TextBoxFor displaying initial value, not the value updated from code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC application that displays a value. This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(DataSites DataSiteList)
{
    if (DataSiteList.Latitude != null)
    {
        DataSites test = new DataSites();
        test.Latitude = "LATITUDE";

        return View(test);
    }
    return View(DataSiteList);
}
public ActionResult SomeInformation()
{
    DataSites test1 = new DataSites();
    test1.Latitude = "LATITUDE2";

     return RedirectToAction("Index", test1);
}
```

The View:

```
@model miniproj2.Models.DataSites

<p>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Latitude)
</p>
```

And the Model:

```
public class DataSites
{
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
}
```

When I go to /Home/SomeInformation, the `DataSites`' `Latitude` property is set to "LATITUDE2". Then redirects to the `Index()` action in the controler, sets the property to "LATITUDE" and returns the view.

When it shows the view, it displays the value "LATITUDE2" as set in the redirect. Shouldn't "LATITUDE" be displayed?

Comment: Install fiddler and watch what actually happens when you call `RedirectToAction` - your answer is there.

Comment: I never use Fiddler , can u give me an explanation ?

Comment: `DataSiteList.Altitude != null` is it a misspelling or the `altitude` property actually exist in your model `DataSites`?

Comment: a ''logical'' explanation because i give to right object to my view ... i dont understand

Comment: Sorry it was a misspelling i just removed it for the post ..

Comment: Inside SomeInformation you are setting test1.Latitude, but Index is checking test1.Altitude for a value. It does not find one so returns DataSiteList not test.

Comment: Try this, replace the `return RedirectToAction("Index", test1);` to `return Index(text1);`.

Comment: @AdrienTancrez Maybe you should start, it's an invaluable debugging tool for web development.

Comment: @AdrienTancrez - If thats a misspelling, I would correct considering that two of your answers so far are pointing this out - but it wouldn't solve your problem anyway.

Comment: @TiagoSilva That's not a great solution as the url won't change.

Comment: @asawyer, well, the solution is to use `TempData` it, as in response JasCav.

Comment: @JasCav I don't disagree I was just mentioning a drawback to the approach in your comment. I'd use a separate action entirely with a directive parameter on the route to accomplish this and keep the thing as stateless as possible.

Comment: @asawyer - I think you pinged the wrong person. I'm not agreeing or disagreeing either way...just giving the response based on my knowledge.

Comment: @JasCav Woops, you are correct.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Your problem is (step by step)

1. Your `SomeInformation()` method sets the value of `test1.Latitude`
   to "LATITUDE2".
2. You then pass that model to your `Index()` method using the overload
   of `RedirectToAction` that accepts an object. Internally this uses
   reflection to build a `RouteValueDictionary` based on the properties
   of your model (in this case its simply `latitude="LATITUDE2"`).
3. When you hit the `Index` method the model is bound by the `DefaultModelBinder` and now the value of `DataSiteList.Latitude` is "LATITUDE2" (which is why you enter
   the `if` block)
4. In the process of binding, the `DefaultModelBinder` sets the
   `ModelState`value of `Latitude` to "LATITUDE2". Any attempts to set
   the value of `Latitude` are now ignored because the view uses
   `ModelState` value to render the control.

It not clear what your trying to do here. You can make it work as you expect by adding `ModelState.Clear();` as the first line of your `Index()` method. This clears all existing `ModelState` values an you can now set the value to "LATITUDE".

But your `if` block makes no sense. Perhaps you were just doing some kind of test, but you may as well remove the parameter from the `Index()` method and just initialize a new instance of `DataSites` in the method.

Edit

To give a bit more information as to why updating a model property has no affect once `ModelState` has been set.

Imagine you have a form to collect user information where the model contains `int Age`. The user is asked to enter their age and someone enters "I'm five next week!". Of course this wont bind to an int so the `DefaultModelBinder` adds the value (the `attemptedValue`) and adds a `ModelStateError`.

When the view is returned it will typically display an error message such as "The field Age must be a number". If the html helper rendering the control used the model value, then it would display "0" (the default value for int). It would be somewhat confusing for the user to see "0" in the textbox and next it a message saying it must be a number (*What! but zero is a number and what the heck happened to what I entered?*). So instead, the helper uses the value from `ModelState` and now the users sees "I'm five next week!" and an associated error message that makes sense for the value.

So even though you thoughts were that *"its not logical"*, there is actually some logic to this behavior.

Answer (score -5):

You are not setting Altitude. It will be null so the code will never go into this block and set Lattitude to "LATTITUDE"

```
    if (DataSiteList.Altitude != null)
    {
        DataSites test = new DataSites();
        test.Latitude = "LATITUDE";

        return View(test);
    }
```

Comment: The value of `Altitude` **is** being set (in the `SomeInformation` method). If the `if` block was not hit then the view would display an empty string not "LATITUDE2" as OP has stated.

Comment: My answer was submitted before the OP fixed that section of the code. Before it was fixed, the code was setting Latitude and Checking Altitude. Now, the code sets Latitude checks Latitude... not altitude, like you have in your comment.

Comment: Altitude or Latitude makes no difference. This has absolutely nothing to do with OP's problem.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually I disagree. If he was setting one property (`Latitude`), then checking another for not being null (`Altitude`) when it was still null, it would never try to re-instantiate `DataSites` and fill that new property (`Latitude`) with anything, because the property being checked (`Altitude`) would've still been null, therefore not meeting that `if` condition.