# Why would an MVC Post (ViewModel) not return updated form using Async?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, asynchronous, viewmodel

Here's the Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(EmailService em)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            await em.Send();

        }
        return View(em);
    }
```

Here's the ViewModel Send; where "this" is an instance of the EmailService class.

```
public async Task<EmailService> Send()
{
    msg = new MailMessage(From, To);
    msg.Body = Body;
    msg.Subject = Subject;
    SetHost();

    try
    {
        await Server.SendMailAsync(msg);
        status = Status.Success;
        Sent = DateTime.Now;
        return this;
    }
    catch (Exception iox)
    {
        status = Status.Failed;
        IOX = iox;
        return this;
    }
}
```

I set a breakpoint here in the controller and saw the status updated correctly, meaning the data was "on it's way to the view as it should have been":  "em" did have the data in it! On this statement.

```
 return View(em);
```

But the view remains in same state just prior to post? Notice the time stamp and the field below it?

[image]

Time to debug the packets, by pressing F12 on the browser on post with a break point set on entry to the controller so it won't respond...  This is the inbound data:

```
To:somebody@email.com
From:somebody@email.com
Subject:This is a test
Body:This is only a test
Sent:1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
status:Initialized
```

This was value of "em" on way out setting break on controller's return View(em):

```
To:somebody@email.com
From:somebody@email.com
Subject:This is a test
Body:"This is only a test"  string
Sent:{11/24/2014 6:48:49 PM}
status:Success
```

Watching the 200 response from browser F12 Network side showed this "old" form data!

```
To:somebody@email.com
From:somebody@email.com
Subject:This is a test
Body:This is only a test
Sent:1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
status:Initialized
```

Any help would be appreciated, it looks like MVC pulled the wrong copy to return after the Asynch controller method returned!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you return a view, the html helpers set the value of the controls from the values in `ModelState`, not the value in the model. The reason for that behavior is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111)

In order to render the updated `Sent` and `Status` properties, you will need to clear `ModelState` for those properties.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(EmailService em)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ModelState.Clear(); // or `ModelState.Remove("Sent"); ModelState.Remove("Status")`
    em = await em.Send();
   }
  return View(em);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I'll try this out today.

Comment: p.s.  I just love MSFT documentation on this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.clear(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Lab results showed this did the trick!  Again thanks Stephen.