# The value of the textbox doesn't change with ViewBag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, viewbag

I wrote a short program but I'm not getting the expected result.  Consider this view which simply is a form with two textboxes and a submit button:

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Index"; }
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBox("Box1", (string)ViewBag.TextBox1)
    @Html.TextBox("Box2", (string)ViewBag.TextBox2)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Box1, string Box2)
{
    ViewBag.TextBox1 = Box2;
    ViewBag.TextBox2 = Box1;
    return View("index",ViewBag);
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to switch the content of textbox1 and textbox2 when someone clicks the submit button.  But no matter what I try it's not working (ie the values stay where they are).  At first I thought may be the `??` has something to do with it but I commented out the lines with `??` but still got the same result. The instead of just doing `return view()` I tried `return view("index", ViewBag)` but that didn't make any difference. Anyone know what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Its because the vales of `Box1` and `Box2` have been added to `ModelState` in your POST method, and the html helpers use the values from `ModelState` when they exist (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) for an explanation. The correct approach is to follow the PRG pattern

Comment: @StephenMuecke  Thank you.  I was totally on wrong path on that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just clear your model state and it will work. Replace your POST method with this code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string Box1, string Box2)
{
    ModelState.Clear();
    ViewBag.TextBox1 = Box2;
    ViewBag.TextBox2 = Box1;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: @herman guzman Thank you.  Accepted answer.  My own answer brought fear and tears into my heart.  I knew it had to be a better way.

Answer (score -2):

Here's what needs to be done on the controller.  Talking about wordy for such a simple task:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string Box1, string Box2)
    {

        ModelState.SetModelValue("Box1", new ValueProviderResult(Box2, string.Empty, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        ModelState.SetModelValue("Box2", new ValueProviderResult(Box1, string.Empty, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));


        return View();
    }
```