# MVC pass model to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My Index.cshtml

```
@model ReportGenerator.WebUI.Models.ReportViewModel
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.report.FileName, new { @class = "form-control", id = "FileName" })
```

My controller

```
public ActionResult Index(ReportViewModel model)
{
    ...some stuff
    model.report = new Report();
    model.report.FileName = "INDEX";
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult fillFields(ReportViewModel _model)
{
    ...some stuff
    _model.report = new Report();
    _model.report.FileName = "FILL";
    return View("Index", _model);
}
```

When I run my application the `TextBox` `Text` property is set to "INDEX". Also when I click on a button which calls the `fillFields` controller action, the `TextBox` is still displaying "INDEX", it's not changing to "FILL".

What am I doing wrong? Why it doesn't want to work?

Comment: Your not doing anything wrong. Your `fillFields()` method has a parameter `ReportViewModel` so its values are added to `ModelState` when the method is initialized. When you return the view, your `TextBoxFor()` method uses the value from `ModelState` (not the model property) to set the value of the textbox. The reason for this is explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111). The correct approach is to follow the PRG pattern

Comment: Thanks ! I've used ModelState.Clear(); and it's working

Comment: Don't use `ModelState.Clear()`. Follow the PRG pattern and redirect!

Comment: ok, I'm going to change it, thanks once again !

Comment: @StephenMuecke Oh, I can't do this. Can you give me some example? I have changed name of methods to "Index" and added [HttpPost] and [HttpGet], still TextBox have got "INDEX"

Comment: Your `Index()` should not have a parameter `ReportViewModel model` (it can fail for numerous reasons and it creates an ugly query string). Its not really clear what your intent is but best guess is it should be `public ActionResult Index(string fileName)` then initialize your model and set the `FileName` property. In the POST method, use `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { fileName = "FILL" });`

Comment: Thanks, now I understand my problem :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke What Should I do if I want to pass many parametrs ? I can't use RedirectToAction because it's now allowing passing multiple params

Comment: Of course you can pass multiple parameters. For example if the method is `public ActionResult Index(string fileName, int number)` then `return RedirectToAction("Index", new { fileName = "FILL" , number = 2 });`. Its impossile to be more speciic if you don't explain what your actually trying to do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke is it possible to pass an object?

Comment: Yes, but (1) if the object contains properties which are complex objects or collections it will fail (2) you can easily exceed the query string limit and throw an exception (3) it creates an ugly query string.

Comment: @StephenMuecke please add an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Mihir Kale has added an answer. You can accept that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@StephenMuecke answered this correctly in the comments above.

Your not doing anything wrong. Your `fillFields()` method has a parameter ReportViewModel so its values are added to ModelState when the method is initialized. When you return the view, your `TextBoxFor()` method uses the value from `ModelState` (not the model property) to set the value of the textbox. The reason for this is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111). The correct approach is to follow the PRG pattern –