# Incorrect List Model Binding indices when using HTML Helpers

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

this is a tricky one to explain, so I'll try bullet pointing.

**Issue:**

1. Dynamic rows (collection) available to user on View (add/delete)
2. User deletes row and saves (POST)
3. Collection passed back to controller with non-sequential indices
4. Stepping through code, everything looks fine, collection items, indices etc.
5. Once the page is rendered, items are not displaying correctly - They are all out by 1 and therefore duplicating the top item at the new 0 location.

**What I've found:**

This happens ONLY when using the HTML Helpers in Razor code.
If I use the traditional `<input>` elements (not ideal), it works fine.

**Question:**

Has anyone ever run into this issue before? Or does anyone know why this is happening, or what I'm doing wrong?

Please check out my code below and thanks for checking my question!

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Car> cars = new List<Car>
        {
            new Car { ID = 1, Make = "BMW 1", Model = "325" },
            new Car { ID = 2, Make = "Land Rover 2", Model = "Range Rover" },
            new Car { ID = 3, Make = "Audi 3", Model = "A3" },
            new Car { ID = 4, Make = "Honda 4", Model = "Civic" }

        };

        CarModel model = new CarModel();
        model.Cars = cars;

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(CarModel model)
    {
        // This is for debugging purposes only
        List<Car> savedCars = model.Cars;

        return View(model);
    }
```

**Index.cshtml:**

As you can see, I have "Make" and "Actual Make" inputs. One being a HTML Helper and the other a traditional HTML Input, respectively.

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="col-md-4">

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Cars.Count; i++)
        {
            <div id="car-row-@i" class="form-group row">
                <br />
                <hr />

                <label class="control-label">Make (@i)</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cars[i].Make, new { @id = "car-make-" + i, @class = "form-control" })

                <label class="control-label">Actual Make</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="car-make-@i" name="Cars[@i].Make" type="text" value="@Model.Cars[i].Make" />

                <div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="Cars.Index" value="@i" />
                </div>

                <br />

                <button id="delete-btn-@i" type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="DeleteCarRow(@i)">Delete Entry</button>

            </div>
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" value="Submit" />
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

**Javascript Delete Function**

```
function DeleteCarRow(id) {

    $("#car-row-" + id).remove();

}
```

**What's happening in the UI:**

[image: Step 1]
Step 1 (delete row)
[image: Step 2]
Step 2 (Submit form)
[image: Step 3]
Step 3 (results)

Comment: In your POST method, add `ModelState.Clear();` just before `return View(model);`. If that fixes the issue, its suggests you code associated with deleting the item is wrong.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks very much for your response. Adding `ModelState.Clear();` worked! I have now added to my OP, the JQuery that I'm using to delete the row. Do you know what I'm missing? Do I need to update the model in some way in this function, after the deletion of the row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that the `HtmlHelper` methods use the value from `ModelState` (if one exists) to set the `value` attribute rather that the actual model value. The reason for this behavior is explained in the answer to [TextBoxFor displaying initial value, not the value updated from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111).

In your case, when you submit, the following values are added to `ModelState`

```
Cars[1].Make: Land Rover 2
Cars[2].Make: Audi 3
Cars[3].Make: Honda 4
```

Note that there is no value for `Cars[0].Make` because you deleted the first item in the view.

When you return the view, the collection now contains

```
Cars[0].Make: Land Rover 2
Cars[1].Make: Audi 3
Cars[2].Make: Honda 4
```

So in the first iteration of the loop, the `TextBoxFor()` method checks `ModelState` for a match, does not find one, and generates `value="Land Rover 2"` (i.e. the model value) and your manual input also reads the model value and sets `value="Land Rover 2"`

In the second iteration, the `TextBoxFor()` does find a match for `Cars[1]Make` in `ModelState` so it sets `value="Land Rover 2"` and manual inputs reads the model value and sets `value="Audi 3"`.

I'm assuming this question is just to explain the behavior (in reality, you would save the data and then redirect to the GET method to display the new list), but you can generate the correct output when you return the view by calling `ModelState.Clear()` which will clear all `ModelState` values so that the `TextBoxFor()` generates the `value` attribute based on the model value.

Side note:You view contains a lot of bad practice, including polluting your markup with behavior (use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)), creating label element that do not behave as labels (clicking on them will not set focus to the associated control), unnecessary use of `<br/>` elements (use css to style your elements with margins etc) and unnecessary use of `new { @id = "car-make-" + i }`. The code in your loop can be

```cs
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Cars.Count; i++)
{
    <div class="form-group row">
        <hr />
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Cars[i].Make, "Make (@i)")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cars[i].Make, new { @class = "form-control" })
        ....
        <input type="hidden" name="Cars.Index" value="@i" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger delete">Delete Entry</button>
    </div>
}

$('.delete').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').remove();
}
```

Comment: Fantastic explanation. This has helped a great deal and I really appreciate you taking the time to comment on my markup as well.