# My UI does not reflect changes to my Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP MVC web app.

I have a partial form and it initally displays 'Hello Andy!'.
I press the submit button and I change this to 'Hello Andy Again!.
I pass the model back to the UI.
The label still shows the old value.

Why?

My markup:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveAlertPreferences", "Users", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "partialform",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "POST",
{
    <div>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_3_of_12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.myStub)
            </div>
            <div class="col span_9_of_12">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myStub)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_3_of_12">
            </div>
            <div class="col span_4_of_12">
                <input type="submit" value="Press me" />
            </div>
            <div class="col span_5_of_12">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My Model:

```
public class ChangeAlertPreferencesModel
{
    public string myStub { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs("HEAD", "GET")]
public PartialViewResult _ChangeAlertPreferences()
{
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";

    ChangeAlertPreferencesModel m = new ChangeAlertPreferencesModel();
    m.myStub = "Hello Andy!";
    return PartialView("_ChangeAlertPreferences", m); 
}

[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult SaveAlertPreferences(ChangeAlertPreferencesModel m)
{
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        m.myStub = "Hello Andy Again!";
        return PartialView("_ChangeAlertPreferences", m);
    }
    else
    {
        m.myStub = "I have errored!";
        return PartialView("_ChangeAlertPreferences", m);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: 1st: is `partialform` the id of the label's parent `div`? 2nd: ajax form and other ajax functionalities "missbehave" if you don't refference jquery-ajax-unobtrusive.js in your project, so make sure you get that. You can download it via NuGet.

Comment: @Spluf Hi, thanks for your time.  Yes partialform is the id of the form's parent.  I will take a look at that framework - thanks

Comment: @CodeCaster thanks. Will take a look

Comment: Its because the `HtmlHelper` methods use values from `ModelState` rather than model properties. This second part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) explains the behavior

Comment: @StephenMuecke cool- thanks

Comment: @closer - am checking that question now. if duplicate I wil ldelete myself :)

Answer (score 0):

To complete my comment, your form statement looks odd,so you might wanna try this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveAlertPreferences", "Users", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "partialform",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    HttpMethod = "POST",
}))
{

        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_3_of_12">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.myStub)
            </div>
            <div class="col span_9_of_12">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.myStub)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_3_of_12">
            </div>
            <div class="col span_4_of_12">
                <input type="submit" value="Press me" />
            </div>
            <div class="col span_5_of_12">
            </div>
        </div>
}
```

To explain, in the first line, the `using` part declares the form and how it should behave, then you end(close) that declaration and open the block that should contain the body of the form.

Comment: Thanks. I had to omit a few lines of code from the using bit as company code I am not allowed to post. The Model IS changing value so it is dow to a caching issue and maybe the framework you suggested wil help :)