# I don't get back the changes of my model in my View Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am starting in asp.net Mvc and making test, i am doing a simple chat using PubNub api and i want finish it using only razor code only and one page only.

Model Chat.cs:

```
 namespace SimpleChat.Models
{
public class Chat
{

    public string NuevoMensaje { get; set; }
    public string TextArea { get; set; }
}
}
```

View:

```
   @model SimpleChat.Models.Chat

   @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Chat",FormMethod.Post))
   {
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NuevoMensaje, "Nuevo Mensaje")
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.NuevoMensaje) 
   <input type="submit"       class="btn-default" value="Enviar" />
   @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.TextArea)
  }
```

Controller:

```
      static string variante = "";
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        pubnub.Subscribe<string>("Chat", subCallback, connecCallBack, errorCallback);
        //Chat nuevochat = new Chat();
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Chat chat)
    {
        pubnub.Publish<string>("Chat", chat.NuevoMensaje, userCallback, puberror);
        chat.NuevoMensaje = "";
        chat.TextArea =variante;
        return View("Index",chat);
    }
    private void subCallback(string obj)
    {
        string[] retorno = obj.Split(',','"');
        variante += "Richard dice:" + retorno[0] + "\n";
    }
```

When i press submit don't get the new data, why?

Comment: What 'new data' are you referring to? Do you mean that your expecting the textbox for `NuevoMensaje` to be reset to any empty string?

Comment: I edited the post, was incomplete check again please

Comment: The comment stands. What are you expecting to happen and what does actually happen?

Comment: the static string variante is the pubnub call back with the sent messages

Comment: Again. What are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening

Comment: i wan't the value of variante  in the TextArea when i press submit and actually don't work, when i press submit i get nothing in the TextArea

Comment: Add `ModelState.Clear();` before your reset the values. Refer the second part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) which explains the behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to render the updated value of `TextArea` property of your view model, You should clear the model state dictionary.

Model state dictionary has the initial values of your form inputs. So when razor (re)render the same view, It gives priority to the content in model state dictionary than the view model object you passed to the view.

You can use the `ModelState.Clear()` method to clear the model state dictionary values before returning to the view.

```
chat.TextArea = variante; 
ModelState.Clear();
return View("Index",chat);
```

Assuming your `variante` variable has the updated text.

Comment: Thanks My Friend was really easy but i am like Jhon Snow in asp.net "i dont know nothing" jejejejeje. Now , My problem is PubNub the var "variante" dont get the new value at time if you test my code you will understand.