# HTTP Post does not return the view in ASP.NET MVC Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

What happens is when i click a link it goes to http get RsvpForm method and return the view. In the view it return has the form. But after i submit the form it does not return back to the reload the view. I confirm this by the value i key in the text box does not cleared. I know how to clear the textbox but my concern was i want it to reload the same view when i click on the submit button which is a post method in the form. Below is my code.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult RsvpForm()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult RsvpForm(GuestResponse guestResponse)
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838799/mvc-retain-values-after-postback) as to why your textbox does not clear. If you want new values you should send a model to your view.

Comment: Generally a POST is better answered by a redirect to a GET action. Otherwise, reloading the page presents a "repost this data?" dialog.

Comment: @Crowcoder: Sending a model to the view does nothing. `ModelState`, not `Model` determines what's displayed in form fields, and `ModelState` is composed primarily from `Request` before `Model`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt that may be true when you use tag helpers but you can certainly put Model values into inputs on POSTing to a View. I agree with your answer but sometimes you want to pre-fill a form.

Comment: That would be for a get. That's the only time model values would not be overridden by request values, typically. However, once you've done a post, even empty posted values will take precedence over any defaults on your model.

Answer (score 3):

When the modelbinder binds request data to a model, it also composes `ModelState` from that data. `ModelState` determines what is displayed in bound form fields, so that's why your field has the posted data in it.

It works this way because if there's an error in the form (it fails server-side validation), you'd normally return the view again so the user can fix their mistake(s). Additionally, you'd want the posted data to be in the appropriate fields, at that point, so the user can just edit what was wrong, instead of having to start completely over filling out the form. Since you're returning the view on "success", this same behavior is occurring, even though there were no validation errors.

Long and short, you should be following the PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern. On post, you return the view only on error. On success, you redirect. If you want the user to see the same form again on success, then simply redirect to the same page. The act of redirecting causes a new GET request, clearing out `ModelState` from the previous POST.