# How avoid passing url query string to the fields in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

When I pass some properties through querystring in url, for instance `..CustomAction?something=10` this value is passe to the view fields.

Suppose some simple POCO Class is simple like this:

```
class MyClass {
    public int something {get;set;}
}
```

whenever or not I set the "somethig" value in controller before calling the view, for instance.

```
public ActionResult CustomAction(int something){
    var entity = new MyClass() { something = 2};
    return view(entity);
}
```

My view always shows the URL parameter `10` instead of `2`

```
@model MyClass
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.something)
```

If the URL is `.../CustomAction` 
the value in the "editorFor" is set to 2 (as expected)

If the URL is `.../CustomAction?something=10` 
the value in the URL (10) overrides the value in the model (2) and the "editorFor" field value  is set to 10.

How can I avoid this parameter override?

Comment: Show the signature of the method. You appear to have your model as a parameter of the method and therefore the value is being added to `ModelState` (so you would need to clear it)

Comment: @StephenMuecke edited on the question

Comment: _My view always shows the URL parameter 10 instead of 2_ - of course it does - the code in that method changes the value of a property, not the value of the url. And add`ModelState.Clear();` before you return the view (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) for an explanation of the behavior)

Comment: Call ModelState.Clear() in your controller or simply change your property value/ parameter name different