# how i can bind data to model with post method asp.mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, viewmodel

My index view  : have text, subtext, and result

```
            <div class="control-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Result, new { @class = "control-label" })
                <div class="controls">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Result, new { @class = "span6" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

My Homecontroller have Action Index

```
[HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel vm)
            {
                var input = vm.Text;
                var subText = vm.SubText;
                IMatchString mString = new MatchStringProvider();
                string result = mString.MatchString(input, subText).ToString();
                vm.Result = String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) ? "no matches" : result;

                return View(vm);
            }
```

when i post data to action Index and return the view but textbox of result not display the result what did i do wrong, help me fix this problem

Comment: Because the value of `Result` is added to `ModelState` and the `TextBoxFor()` method uses `ModelState` values to set the value if they exist (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) for more detail). You can use `ModelState.Clear();` before updating the value, but the correct approach is to use the PRG pattern and redirect.

Comment: I don't think @StephenMuecke's answer is correct. You can alter the view model data before rendering it. If you put a breakline on the first line of that method do you see the correct values in the "vm" parameter? Also, what are your form data keys/values?

Comment: @PeterMorris, Read the link!

Comment: i used return RedirectToAction("Index", vm); and this worked

Comment: I stand (sit) corrected, thank you

Comment: @StephenMuecke Now that I think of it I recall seeing this behaviour. I remember writing some HtmlHelper methods for dropdown lists. I can't believe it slipped my mind that ValueProviders take priority over the ViewModel. Oh well, thanks for correcting me :)