# Strange Form behavior with Submit ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Doesn't seem like this should work so I have no idea why it does. I LIKE the result, but worried I can't depend on it because I have no idea how it is working.

```
[HttpGet]  
public ActionResult Modify(System.Guid id)
{
  return View("Modify", LoadFromDatabase(id));
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Modify(CaseModel myModel)
{
  //So odd behavior. If I redirect to the actual GET Modify, 
  //I loose any changes on the form. however if I perform the 
  //same actions but here in the Post... all my unsaved changes 
  //stick..why?

  //This one wipes any edits
  return RedirectToAction("Modify", new { id = myModel.ID});

  //This one actually leaves all my changes, even though 
  //I am re-creating the model from the database just like
  //the other ActionResult
  return View("Modify", LoadFromDatabase(myModel.ID));
}
```

Comment: You can depend on it. `RedirectToAction()` is redirecting to a new page which initializes a new instance of `CaseModel` based on `ID` property (i.e. reads the values from your repository. `return View()` is returning the current instance of `CaseModel` and if you using the `HtmlHelper` methods to generate form controls, it will use the values from `ModelState` which are added by the `DefaultModelBinder` when you submit the form

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) for more explanation of the behavior). `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.someProperty)` will display the value you posted, whereas `@Model.someProperty` will display the 'updated' value you set in the post method

Comment: Perfect!... I did not know that the HTML helpers overwrite my Model values with the ModelState (aka ViewState?).... That explains it... THANKS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Stephen Muecke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) mentions in the [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936865/strange-form-behavior-with-submit-actionresult/41000315#comment69138968_40936865) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40936865/strange-form-behavior-with-submit-actionresult/41000315#comment69139005_40936865) above,

> You can depend on it. `RedirectToAction()` is redirecting to a new page which initializes a new instance of `CaseModel` based on `ID` property (i.e. reads the values from your repository. `return View()` is returning the current instance of `CaseModel` and if you using the `HtmlHelper` methods to generate form controls, it will use the values from `ModelState` which are added by the `DefaultModelBinder` when you submit the form. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) for more explanation of the behavior). `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.someProperty)` will display the value you posted, whereas `@Model.someProperty` will display the 'updated' value you set in the post method

works perfectly. The HTML helpers overwrite my Model values with the ModelState (aka ViewState).