# Is there a way to clear an @Html.TextAreaFor

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, textarea

I am using asp.net core razor engine.  After I enter text in my TextArea and hit the submit button I want to clear the text in the TexArea.  I have not been able to find anything on how to do this using html or c#.
Here is my code for the TextAreaFor

```
 <h1>Add Your Comment</h1>
                @using(Html.BeginForm("AddComment","Home"))
                {
                    <p>
                        <label>Your Comment</label>
                        @Html.TextAreaFor(d=>d.comment)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(d => d.comment)
                    </p>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add my Comment!"/>
                }
```

Here is my controller for AddComment

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("addComment")]
        public IActionResult AddComment(Messages model)
        {  
            var user_id = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Id");
            if(user_id == null){
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            model.Users_id = Convert.ToInt32(user_id.ToString());
            userFactory.addComment(model, user_id);
            setTempData();

            ViewBag.Messages = userFactory.FindAll();
            model.comment ="";
            return View("Login", model);  
        }
```

The calls for userFactory work, it is a call to my factory that talks to my db

Comment: Only with JavaScript, I'm afraid: `document.getElementById("formId").addEventListener("submit", function() { this.innerText = ""; })`, something like that.

Comment: What do you do after you submit? Handle the response in a controller action? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You should expand your post a little with more detail, or more code. I guess your entire application is more than this snippet.

Comment: @ArveSystad, I added my controller method.  The code sends the user input to my db.  I am trying to figure out is there is a way to clear the data in the textareas after that data has been submitted to the db

Comment: Do not return the view. Follow the PRG pattern and redirect back to the GET method that generates the view. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) for an explanation of the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

After all the work is done, you should not `return View(...)`, but rather redirect the user to it with [`RedirectToAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx) . By doing that, you clear out all form fields, and make use of the [Post-redirect-get pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), which stops your users from double-submitting.

The same pattern should nearly always be applied when you post an entire page.