# Why is Html.EditorFor() / Html.HiddenFor() incorrectly mapping an ID field?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an MVC 5.2.3 web project.

I have a model:

```
public class InstanceOnboarding : IInstanceOnboarding
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int InstanceID { get; set; }
    public string InstanceName { get; set; }
    //etc...
}
```

And I am displaying the model with Html.EditorFor like so:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model, "InstanceOnboarding")
```

In Views/Shared/EditorTemplates I have my InstanceOnboarding.cshtml file that defines how EditorFor() is supposed to be mapping it:

```
@model Models.InstanceOnboarding

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.InstanceID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AuditFileID)
//etc...
```

However, when the page loads and I inspect element in Chrome, I see this:

```
<input ... id="ID" name="ID" type="hidden" value="240">
<input ... id="InstanceID" name="InstanceID" type="hidden" value="240">
```

even though 240 is the value of `InstanceID`, and 0 is the value of `ID`.  I know they are because I can see them in the viewModel right before the page loads.  Makes no sense!

Any idea how this is happening?

EDIT: I have experimented with setting the ID to not be 0; that doesn't make a difference.

EDIT 2: Showing controller method by request:
[image: Controller method with inspecting the value]
(The black areas are redacted information.)

Comment: You need to show your GET method (I assume you have a parameter named `id` and you then set the value of `InstanceID` to the value of that parameter)

Comment: As s side note, it should be `@Html.EditorFor(model => model)` and your `InstanceOnboarding.cshtml` EditorTemplate should be located in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` (or `/Views/YourControllerName/EditorTemplates` folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue occurs because your method has a parameter `id`. If you navigate to the method using `../EditOnboarding/240`, the `DefaultModelBinder` adds `id: 240` to `ModelState` (I assume your `ShowitOnboarding()` method sets the value of `InstanceID` to the value of `id`, but does not set the `id` value).

All the `HtmlHelper` methods that generate form controls first check the values in `ModelState` and if they exist (which in your case does for `id`), they use that value rather that the actual property value (the 2nd part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) explains the behavior).

One way to solve this is to call `ModelState.Clear()` before returning the view (this removes all values from `ModelState` and the `HtmlHelper` methods will then use the model property value). Another alternative is to change the method parameter to `int InstanceID` (and add a specific route definition for the method is you want to create a route rather than a query string)

Comment: Thank you!  That was it.  All I did was change the controller parameter to a different name ( `InstanceID` instead of `ID` ) and that fixed it.  It's also good to know there is an actual reason it's behaving this way.  I wish it was documented.