# Form POST parameters wrong generated after return view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have this CSHTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteProduct", "Shop", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Hidden("productId", product.ProductId);
    @Html.Hidden("productVariantId", product.ProductVariantId);
    @Html.Hidden("quantity", product.Quantity);
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
}
```

That calls this backend:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteProduct(int productId, int? productVariantId, int quantity)
{
    //...product gets deleted, etc. Not important for this question

    //regenerate the view, same as when loading the 'Order' view initially
    OrderWrapperViewModel model = GenerateOrderWrapperModel();
    return View("Order", model);
}
```

loading Order view in controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Order()
{
    OrderWrapperViewModel model = GenerateOrderWrapperModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

When I first call delete, I delete a product with ID: `7` and a product variant ID: `8`. All goes fine. But after the page is returned, product with ID 7 is not listed anymore, only product with ID 1. So the second time it should be product ID: `1` and product variant ID: `4`.

When returning from `DeleteProduct`, the url is currently showing /Shop/DeleteProduct. When I debug through the razor code:

[image: generate form]

Seems correct, right?

Well, the html is different:

[image: different html]

Of course, clicking the button passes those incorrect parameters as well. I can assure you that this is the same button, there is only 1 product shown at that time.

I solved it by simply redirecting to Order view again, so I am more interested in *why* this happens. Reason is, because for others I am returning a error message (using `ModelState`). That of course doesn't work when I redirect.

It also happens in production environment.

Comment: The correct approach is to follow the PRG pattern so just do it. But for an explanation of the behavior, refer [TextBoxFor displaying initial value, not the value updated from code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111)

Answer (score 2):

this is expected behavior this happens when you try to change values of `Model` just like you did in `DeleteProduct` the reason it was getting the old values because when you return to the same view, values from  `ModelState` are rendered first so if `ModelState` is empty it will populate values from `Model` so thats why we use

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

if you are changing the values in `Model` you have to clear values from `ModelState` first. You can place a breakpoint and check the `value` of `key` it will look like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of performing such operations as `DeleteProduct` is to redirect to another action after the deletion is completed:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteProduct(int productId, int? productVariantId, int quantity)
{
    //...product gets deleted, etc. Not important for this question

    return RedirectToAction("Order");
}
```

This way you get a fresh `ModelState` in your `Order` method so that it doesn't conflict with any `Model` parameters you're passing to the view, and the user sees a 'more correct' URL in their browser after the product is deleted (e.g. `/Shop/Order` instead of `/Shop/DeleteProduct`).