# set select value in IEnumerable<SelectListItem> c# mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, selectlistitem

I have a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

My ViewModel

```
public class StatusClass
{
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusList { get; set; }
}
```

I set values in to `StatusList` from my controller.

```
StatusClass statusObj = new CRM.StatusClass();

List<SelectListItem> Discountdata = new List<SelectListItem>();
        Discountdata.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "All", Text = "All" });
        Discountdata.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "Draft", Text = "Draft" });
        Discountdata.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "Issued", Text = "Issued" });
        Discountdata.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "Partial", Text = "Partially Received" });
        Discountdata.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "Received", Text = "Received" });
        Discountdata.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "PAID", Text = "Paid" });
        Discountdata.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "Billed", Text = "Billed" });

        statusObj.StatusList = new SelectList(Discountdata, "Value", "Text");
```

This works fine and my HTML is like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, Model.StatusList)
```

> What i want is, I need to set the selected value from the controller when the list get created.

Suppose I have a string like this:

```
string newwStatus = "Issued";
```

How can I set it as selected in the `SelectListItem`.

I tried this, but its not working in my case:

```
foreach(var item  in StatusList)
{
    if(item.value == status)
    {
        item.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

and tries this too:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList =
    from s in StatusList
        select new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = (s.Value == status),
            Text = s.Text,
            Value = s.Value
        };
```

I dont know if these are the right way if someone know how to do this, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is ignored when binding to a model property. You need to set the value of your `Status` property in the GET method before you pass the model to the view

```
List<SelectListItem> Discountdata = new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "All", Text = "All" },
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "Draft", Text = "Draft" },
    new SelectListItem() { Value = "Issued", Text = "Issued" },
    ....

};
StatusClass model = new CRM.StatusClass
{
    StatusList = Discountdata,
    Status = "Issued"
};
return View(model);
```

and the 2nd option in your `<select>` element will be selected.

Note that `Discountdata` is already `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and using `new SelectList(Discountdata, "Value", "Text")` to create an identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` is unnecessary extra overhead.

Note also that since you have the same value for both the `value` attribute and display text, you could simply use

```
List<string> Discountdata = new List<string>{ "All", "Draft", "Issued", ... };
```

and in the model constructor

```
StatusList = new SelectList(Discountdata),
```

Comment: I dont know why but its not working for me. It still showing first item as selected

Comment: Then your doing something else wrong! Is this in an `EditorTemplate` where the model is a collection?

Comment: And you can take a look at this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OxriS9) which is associated with [this answer](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OxriS9) to prove it

Comment: Another possible cause is you have a parameter `string status` in your GET method (or a model with a property of that name) and its value is not "Issued"`

Comment: Changing `status` to new name worked :), Thanks

Comment: Then I assume you did have a parameter `string status` in the method? The value of the parameter is added to `ModelState` by the `DefaultModelBinder` and the `HtmlHelper` methods use values from `ModelState` if they exist (to understand the behavior, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111)

Answer (score 0):

You're binding `Status` property to the dropdown. So set the value either from database, or in your case, a default value "Issued" like this:

```
statusObj.Status = "Issued"
```

Comment: I tried but it still showing the first item

Comment: i did have a parameter `string status` in the method, so changed the name to new and this code woks