# Viewbag Fed DropdownFor - Removes Selected property once Action has Param

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

Ok All Weird one here ....

I have a view with a dropdown list containing 4 days prior and todays date...

When Index(Action) is lauched with a null for DateTime the DropDownList appears with the current date already selected... Great!

**HTML SOURCE URL \Controller\Index**

```
    <select class="form-control" id="Date" name="Date" onchange="Change_Date(this)"
    <option value="23/10/2017">23/10/2017</option>
    <option value="24/10/2017">24/10/2017</option>
    <option value="25/10/2017">25/10/2017</option>
    <option value="26/10/2017">26/10/2017</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="27/10/2017">27/10/2017</option>
    </select>
```

When Index(Action) is launched with a DateTime, even though it goes through the exact same process and I can physically see the Selected=True property in the ViewBag.DateList... the dropdown has no selected option and reverts to the first.

**HTML SOURCE URL \Controller\Index?date=2017-10-26**

```
    <select class="form-control" id="Date" name="Date" onchange="Change_Date(this)"
    <option value="23/10/2017">23/10/2017</option>
    <option value="24/10/2017">24/10/2017</option>
    <option value="25/10/2017">25/10/2017</option>
    <option value="26/10/2017">26/10/2017</option>
    <option value="27/10/2017">27/10/2017</option>
    </select>
```

I have tried bypassing the JS and putting the datetime directly in the URL but no luck so its not that...

I cannot understand why having ?date=*date* in the URL removes the selected property from the options elements...

Just to be Clear in both instances the Selected = True Property is present within the ViewBag.DateList, but it doesn't render as expected when a parameter is passed into the action.

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("Date", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DateList, 
    new { @class = "form-control", @onchange="Change_Date(this)" })
```

**Method**

```
  public ActionResult Index(DateTime? date)
    {
        if (date.HasValue == false)
        {
            date = DateTime.Now.Date;
        }
        List<SelectListItem> Dates = new List<SelectListItem>();
        for (int i = -4; i < 1; i++)
        {
            string date_display = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(i).ToShortDateString();
            Dates.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = date_display, Value =date_display});
        }

        foreach (SelectListItem item in Dates)
        {
            if (item.Value == date.ToShortDateString())
                item.Selected = true;
        }
        ViewBag.DateList = Dates;
     }
```

**JS**

```
function Change_Date(val)
{
    var value = $('#Date').val();
    value = value.split("/").reverse().join("-");
    var url = "/Controller/Index?date=" + value;
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?date=date` in your url adds a value for `date` to `ModelState` because you have a parameter named `date` in your method. The `HtmlHelper` methods that generate form controls use the value from `ModelState` for binding if it exists (then from `ViewData` and finally from the actual model property). Refer the 2nd part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) for an explanation of the behavior.

Internally the `DropDownList()` (and `DropDownListFor()`) method builds a new `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and sets the value of the `Selected` property based on the property your binding to (in your case `Date`) if its not `null`.

When you redirect using `../Controller/Index?date=2017-10-26`, the value of the `date` parameter (and the `ModelState` value) becomes `26/10/2017 12:00:00 AM`. When the `DropDownList()` method builds its `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` by looping through `ViewBag.DateList`, it compares the `.ToString()` property of your `SelectListItem` values with the value of `date` in `ModelState` and does not find any match (the string `"26/10/2017 12:00:00 AM"` is not equal to `"26/10/2017"`) so no options are set as selected.

Some options to have the correct option selected include

1. Adding `ModelState.Clear()` in the controller method before you
   return the view.
2. Changing either the name of the parameter in the method, or the name
   in the dropdownlist so they do not match, for example
   `@Html.DropDownList("SelectedDate", ...)`

Comment: Very Nice... Thanks for the very clear explanation on top of the answer. I didn't know ModelState took from the URL's