# How to fill in and submit three forms (based on the same model) on the same page from the view to the controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm programming a web app (in mvc) where a 'quizmaster' can add questions. A quiz contains 3 questions.

I would like to achieve that the quizmaster can add both 3 questions on the same page/form.

The problem is that I only know how to submit one question and not three of them.

So I created a view (AddQuestions), two models (Question and Quiz) and a controller (QuizController).

The view is strongly typed with the Question model.
On this view I have a form. At the moment I have a for loop that loops till three, so that 3 questions can be filled in. They are all in one form.

Model

```cs
public class Question
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public double Points { get; set; }
    }
```

The Quiz class contains an Id, Date and fields to save the Id's of the three questions

View

```cs
<form asp-action="AddQuestions" method="post">
            @{
                for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        <span>Question 1</span>
                    }
                    else if (i == 1)
                    {
                        <span>Question 2</span>
                    }
                    else if (i == 2)
                    {
                        <span>Question 3</span>
                    }

                    <p>
                        <label asp-for="Question[i]">Question</label>
                        <input asp-for="Question[i]" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label asp-for="Answer[i]">Answer</label>
                        <input asp-for="Answer[i]" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label asp-for="Points[i]">Points</label>
                        <input asp-for="Points[i]" />
                    </p>
                }
            }
            <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ViewResult AddQuestions(IEnumerable<Question> questionList)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

I expect the output of questionList is a list of Questions (so I can add these question to the Quiz), but there is no output, because there occured two (the same) errors in the view.

The error is:

> "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'double'"
>   This error references to the asp-for="Points[i]" parts.

How can I achieve that the quizmaster can fill in three questions (of the model Question) (for one quiz) at the same page?

Comment: Is your view using a List<Question> as  @Model??

Comment: @leandro.andrioli No model is just Question. If I change it to List<Question> I will get a lot of errors (for each property):
'List<Question>' does not contain a definition for 'Question' and no accessible extension method 'Question' accepting a first argument of type 'List<Question>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

Your Model on the View page like this: `@model List<Models.Question>`
from this take the model count like below

```
for(int i=0;i<model.count;i++)
{
//Your form tags
}
```

and at the controller side use the `foreach` loop to retrieve the data of the form.
refer this: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019501/asp-net-mvc-form-includes-for-loop-over-form-controllers)