# Model Value is not setting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating an CRUD Application in Asp.Net Core

After Add Operation I am redirecting to same view with setting model value as null to get another entry

Below is my code

```
public IActionResult Add(OptionMasterVM model)
    {
        try
        {
            model.QuestionList = context.QuestionMaster.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.QuestionName, Value = x.QuestionId.ToString() }).ToList();

            if (HttpContext.Request.Method == "POST")
            {
                OptionMaster _optionmaster = new OptionMaster();
                _optionmaster = model.OptionMaster;
                using (var ctx = new QuestionnaireEntities(_configuration))
                {
                    ctx.OptionMaster.Add(_optionmaster);
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
                TempData["Msg"] = "Option Added Successfully , Add Another Option";
                model.OptionMaster.OptionValue = string.Empty;
                model.OptionMaster.OptionRating = 0;
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.LogError(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Here I am setting Option Value to empty and rating to Zero to take next entry , but on view it does not show empty and zero , on view it show previously filled value.

[image]

After Setting below code these two fields should be reset but they don't

```
model.OptionMaster.OptionValue = string.Empty;
model.OptionMaster.OptionRating = 0;
```

Is there any other way to set model object as null in Asp.net Core ?

Comment: Is it Ajax request ?

Comment: You are not _redirecting to same view_ (to do that you would use `RedirectToAction()`). And to explain the behavior, refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111). If you want to display the view with a different model then follow the PRG pattern

Comment: "OptionMaster _optionmaster = new OptionMaster();
                _optionmaster = model.OptionMaster;" - that makes no sense, too. Unnecessary object creation.

Comment: @lucky no , its not Ajax request

Comment: @StephenMuecke , Thanks , All I need is ModelState.Clear() before resetting model object

Comment: @Fildor Thanks to you too , W

Comment: Do it properly by redirecting to a separate `[HttpGet]` method (which will not have a parameter for the model)

Comment: @StephenMuecke , That's complicated , having two actionMethod for one purpose

Comment: No it is not, and it the standard way

Comment: And you cannot get any client side or server side validation with your current implementation

Answer (score 2):

This can happen because Razor helpers use values from ModelState, rather than the model itself. Your OptionValue is probably displayed using a helper, for example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OptionMaster.OptionValue)
```

When you change model values within an action, you need remove the old values from ModelState before rendering the View.

The easiest way of doing this is to call [ModelState.Clear()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.clear(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
model.OptionMaster.OptionValue = string.Empty;
model.OptionMaster.OptionRating = 0;

ModelState.Clear();     // ensure these changes are rendered in the View

return View(model);
```

Answer (score 1):

The values displayed for bound form fields come from `ModelState`, which is composed based on values from `Request`, `ViewData`/`ViewBag`, and finally `Model`. After posting, obviously, you'll have values set in `Request`, which will therefore be the values in `ModelState`. It works this way, so that when there's a validation error and the user is returned to the form to correct their mistakes, the values they posted will be there for them to edit.

Long and short, you need to follow the PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern. Essentially, after posting, you only return the view on error. If the post is successful, you *redirect*. This not only clears `ModelState`, but also prevents accidental re-posts if the user attempts to refresh the page.

If you want to take the user back to the same view, simply redirect to the same action, but you need to do a redirect, not return the view.