# (MVC 5) Refresh DropDownListFor Selected Value while updating Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a Partial View with a DropDownListFor-Element.

**Partial View**

```
@model Person

<h4>Show me OrganizationID: @Model.Organization_ID</h4>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Organization_ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.AllOrganizations, "ID", "Name"))
```

Now when updating the Partial View via JQuery and change the "Organization_ID" of the model in the controllers action method, the selected item of DropDownListFor will be not changed after update, even though the organization exists in the DropDownList!

**JQuery** (in Create.cshtml)

```
var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("ReloadPerson", "Home"))';
$('#divPerson').load(url, $('#formPerson').serializeArray());
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ReloadPerson([Bind(Include = "ID,  [...], Organization_ID")] Person person)
{
      ViewBag.AllOrganizations = _ecmManager.GetAllOrganizations ();
      person.Organisation_ID = (Guid)TempData["Organization_ID"];

      return PartialView("Person", person);
 }
```

The action method puts via TempData a new ID in the property of my object and send it back to the Partial View model. The h4-header shows me after updating the new organization-id, but my DropDownListFor-Element doesn't select the organization he get from the model.

The functionality of DropDownListFor is tested:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.AllOrganizations = _ecmManager.GetAllOrganisationen();

    return View(new Person() { Organization_ID = _ecmManager.GetOrganizationByID(new Guid("E2A9C501-1E53-4074-9B4B-04C693FB753A")).ID });
}
```

I've tested the functionality, when loading my View with an explicit model and it works how it should. The dropdownlistfor auto-selected the organization from its modelbinding.

**So, how can I update my DropDownListFor-Element after Partial View Update (no reloading of the whole page via JQuery)?**

Comment: The dropdownlist will display the value you initially posted because its been added to `ModelState`. You can use `ModelState.Clear()` to remove it and display your new value. (refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111) for an explanation of the behavior)

Comment: Thank you mate! Thank you!!