# View displays different values, then it has in its model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

### Short overview

I have a very curious bug and I have absolutetly no idea where it is coming from. I want to create a webpage, where you can modify a table and out of this table you can generate a table in the database. For that I am using ASP .NET MVC 4 and I am already able to modify and create the table in the database, but I have a small "+" button, where I want to insert cells into the table (model).

**Problem**

> It already works, but it is inserting it always at the last index AND the name is also equal to the one, which was last before. (same for deleting with "-" button)

Here two screenshots:
**Before clicking:**
[image: before]
**After clicking:**
[image: after]

### Code

To achieve that all I have created two models:

#### CreateTableModel

I initialize the Model with one column. (I have more proerties and functions which are not relevant)

```
public class CreateTableModels
{
    public CreateTableModels()
    {
        Columns = new List<CreateTableColumnModels>() { new CreateTableColumnModels(){ PrimaryKey = true } };
    }

    [Required]
    [UniqueNamesValidation(ErrorMessage="Alle Namen müssen unique sein")]
    [Display(Name = "Columns")]
    public List<CreateTableColumnModels> Columns { get; private set; }

    //more properties...
```

This Model has a list of **CreateTableColumnModels**:

```
public class CreateTableColumnModels
{
    public CreateTableColumnModels()
    {
        Name = "name";
        NotNull = false;
        PrimaryKey = false;
        Length = 1;
    }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Typ")]
    public System.Data.SqlDbType Type { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Darf nicht leer sein!")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "Nur Buchstaben und Zahlen sind erlaubt")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //more properties...
```

#### Controller

In the controller i want to insert a column to the model (if the button was pressed it sends the index via addCell). The column should have the name "Added". If I Add a new column it works fine.

```
public class CreateTableController : Controller
{
    public ViewResult Index(CreateTableModels model, int count = 1, int? addCell = null, int? removeCell = null, bool createTable = false)
    {
        if (addCell != null)
        {
            model.Columns.Insert(addCell.Value, new CreateTableColumnModels() { Name = "ADDED", Type = System.Data.SqlDbType.Float });
        }
```

### View

I did put nearly the whole view here, because I have absolutely no clue where the problem is located.

```
<h2>CreateTable</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "CreateTable", FormMethod.Get))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
</div>
<table id="table" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Columns.FirstOrDefault().Type)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Columns.FirstOrDefault().Length)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Columns.FirstOrDefault().Precision)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Columns.FirstOrDefault().Name)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Columns.FirstOrDefault().NotNull)</th>
            <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Columns.FirstOrDefault().PrimaryKey)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="TableSelection">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => Model.Columns[i].Type, new SelectList(Model.Columns[i].Types), new { @ID = "typeSelection", @class = "form-control", @style = "width:150px;" })
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="Length">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Columns[i].Length, new { @ID = "length", @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @style = "width:80px", @disabled = "disabled" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Columns[i].Length)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="Precision">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Columns[i].Precision, new { @ID = "precision", @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @style = "width:80px", @disabled = "disabled" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Columns[i].Precision)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="Name">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.Columns[i].Name, new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:150px" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => Model.Columns[i].Name)
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="NotNull">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => Model.Columns[i].NotNull, new { @ID = "notNull", @checked = Model.Columns[i].NotNull, @class = "checkbox" })
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="PrimaryKey">
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Columns[i].PrimaryKey, new { @ID = "primaryKey", @checked = Model.Columns[i].PrimaryKey, @class = "checkbox" })
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="addCell" value="@i">+</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="removeCell" value="@i">-</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<div align="left" class=" form-group" style="display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: flex-start; align-items: center;">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TableName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    </div>
    <div class="text-center control-form">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TableName, new { @class = "text-center control-form" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TableName)
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" style="margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px;" name="createTable" value="true" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
    </div>
    <div>
        @if (Model.WorkDone != null && (bool)Model.WorkDone)
        {
            <label style="font-size:medium" class="label label-success">Alle Änderungen wurden gespeichert!</label>
        }
        else if (Model.WorkDone != null)
        {
            <label style="font-size:medium" class="label label-danger">Es ist etwas schief gelaufen!</label>
        }
    </div>
</div>
}
```

### Debug

Also if I debug it till the end of the view, it has the right values.
[image: debug]

The only thing I can imagine changing it is the `@RenderBody()` in the `_Layout.cshtml` file. Is there anyone who had something similar or can help me? Already thanks for reading to the end :)

Comment: MVC renders POSTed values instead of values assigned in the controller.

Comment: @CodeCaster Which posted values exactly do you mean? I have checked all GET parameters and they seemed OK.

Comment: Before adding an answer (the issue is related to `ModelState`), can you confirm that `public List<CreateTableColumnModels> Columns { get; private set; }` is a typo? - you have a private setter which means that none of your posted values are bound (because the `DefaultModelBinder` cannot **set** them), and you model in the POST method will only contain 1 new item (the one you added in the constructor). I assume that it must actually be `public List<CreateTableColumnModels> Columns { get; set; }` otherwise you would only see 2 items when the view is returned

Comment: @StephenMuecke I made the setter publi, but nothing changed. As shown in the Debug image, The model has the right columns (even in the view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when you submit your collection, the posted values are added to `ModelState`. If we look at just the `Name` property, the following values are added

```
Columns[0].Name // value = "a"
Columns[1].Name // value = "b"
Columns[2].Name // value = "c"
```

Now you insert a new column (say before the first item). The values in the model are now

```
Columns[0].Name // value = "ADDED"
Columns[1].Name // value = "a"
Columns[2].Name // value = "b"
Columns[3].Name // value = "c"
```

Now when you return the view, you (correcty) use the `HtmlHelper` methods to generate the view, but all the `HtmlHelper` methods that generate form controls render the `value` attribute by checking the following (in order)

1. the value in `ModelState` (if any)
2. the value in the `ViewDataDictionary` (if any)
3. the value from the model

The reason for this behavior is explained in [TextBoxFor displaying initial value, not the value updated from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111).

In the first iteration of the `for` loop, your `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Columns[i].Name)` sees a value of "a" in `ModelState` and renders "a" in the textbox (even though the value of the model is "ADDED").

In the 2nd iteration, the value is again taken from `ModelState`, so "b" is rendered.

In the 3rd iteration, the value is again taken from `ModelState`, so "c" is rendered.

And in the 4th and final iteration, a value is not found in `ModelState` (or `ViewData`) for `Columns[3].Name`, so it reads the value from the model, so "c" is rendered.

As a side note, if you added `@Model.Columns[i].Name` in a table cell, you would see the values rendered in accordance with the property value i.e. Row 1: "ADDED", Row 2: "a", Row 3: "b", Row4: "c".

To solve this, you can add `ModelState.Clear()` before your return the view. However, the side effect of this is that it also clears any validation errors, so at the least, you should immediately return the view if `ModelState` is not valid

```
public ViewResult Index(CreateTableModels model, ...)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }
    ... // code to insert new row
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(model);
}
```

However, the best approach is to follow the PRG pattern and redirect to a method that generates the new data.