# ASP.net Core Required attribute automatically triggers in Edit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, required

I want to know what is the possible reason why required attributes automatically triggers in Edit even though the field is not empty?

Here is my code:

View Model

```
public class ExpensesViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(4, MinimumLength = 4)]
    [Remote(action: "IsExpenseCodeValid", controller: "Expenses", AdditionalFields = "Id", 
        ErrorMessage = "Expense Code already taken, please try different")]
    public string Expense_Code { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Expense_Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Updated_By { get; set; }
}
```

Edit.cshtml code:

```
  @*@model QnE_Accounting.Models.MasterModels.Expenses*@
@model QnE_Accounting.Models.MasterViewModels.ExpensesViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

<h4>Expenses</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Expense_Code" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Expense_Code" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Expense_Code" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            etc..
```

And Edit from Controller:

```
// GET: Expenses/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id, ExpensesViewModel vmodel)
  {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var expenses = await _context.Expenses.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

        if (expenses == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            vmodel.Id = expenses.Id;
            vmodel.Expense_Code = expenses.Expense_Code;
            vmodel.Expense_Name = expenses.Expense_Name;
            vmodel.Category = expenses.Category;
        }

        return View(vmodel);
    }
```

Update, sample screen shot:

[Sample screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWmcY.png)

How can I possibly fix this issue? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, which field? What's the error? And what is the value?

Comment: What do you mean _automatically triggers in Edit_?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, already included screen shot sir, field that has Required attribute

Comment: You need to remove the `ExpensesViewModel vmodel` parameter from your method (and initialize the model inside the method). To understand what is happening, refer [TextBoxFor displaying initial value, not the value updated from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Hi Sir already fix the problem. followed your advice..thank you

Answer (score 0):

Fix the issue by removing the viewmodel parameter and declare it inside the function, thanks

```
// GET: Expenses/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    //public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var expenses = await _context.Expenses.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
        //if (expenses == null)
        //{
        //    return NotFound();
        //}

        //return View(expenses);

        ExpensesViewModel vmodel = new ExpensesViewModel();

        if (expenses == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            vmodel.Id = expenses.Id;
            vmodel.Expense_Code = expenses.Expense_Code;
            vmodel.Expense_Name = expenses.Expense_Name;
            vmodel.Category = expenses.Category;
        }

        return View(vmodel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create an Edit method to handle the Post

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id, ExpensesViewModel vmodel)
{
    ... perform edit
}
```