# Missing value attribute .net core mvc HiddenFor helper

Tags: c#, .net, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

For some reason the HiddenFor helper in .NET Core  (2.1.4) MVC is not setting a value on the hidden input element despite a value being present on the model property it represents.

If I manually create a hidden attribute and use IdFor, NameFor and manually set the value it works as expected.

```
    // This works and has a value attribute with a value
    <input type="hidden" id="@Html.IdFor(x => x.Fields[componentIndex].Value)" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Fields[componentIndex].Value)" value="@Model.Fields[componentIndex].Value"/>

    // This has a value attribute but it's empty
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Fields[componentIndex].Value)
```

Note in both cases the generated names and id's are the same.

If I use a HiddenFor and provide a `new { @Value=... }` with the value it also doesn't set.

The only difference between the HiddenFor's that set a value (using the same code but a different component index) is that they are supplied on post and this problematic one is set in the controller.

Comment: You need to show you controller code (most likely a `ModelState` issue - refer [TextBoxFor displaying initial value, not the value updated from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654862/textboxfor-displaying-initial-value-not-the-value-updated-from-code/26664111#26664111))

Comment: Share us the content of  `.csproj` or a project to reproduce your issue. I made a test with `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)` under `Asp.net Core 2.1` and upgrade `Microsoft.NETCore.App` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` to `2.1.4`, the result is correctly `<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="1">`

Answer (score 5):

In `ASP.NET Core` you could use [tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro) `asp-for` so the hidden will look like:

```
<input asp-for="ModelPropertyName" type="hidden" />
```

**But for binding lists** to `POST` controller actions sometimes it is easier to render hiddens explicitly (like you do) because hidden input **names should follow the collection binding naming format like `Fields[i].Value`**, where `i` is collection index.

For more details about collection binding check [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/asp-net/model-binding-asp-net-core/)

Comment: This works for me: <input asp-for="ModelPropertyName" type="hidden" value="@Model.PropertyName" /> ?